# How to link just the image not the whole row with link_to

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

link_to it link the whole row not just the image in my code

```
<div class="logo"><h1><%= link_to root_path do %><%= image_tag "v.jpg",id:"second"%><% end %> <span id="margin"><%= image_tag "AppleNeon.jpg",id:"third"%> <%= image_tag "AndroidNeon.jpg",id:"third"%> </span></h1> </div>
```

css

```
.logo{
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:300;
}
.logo a{
  font-family: "Product Sans Bold";
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900 !important;
  color: white;
}
.logo a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo a:active{
  text-decoration: none;
}

 #second{
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.logo #third{
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  
}
#margin{
  float: right;
  margin-top: -67px !important;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the html codes?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean. This seems like a markup question, not a styling one.

Comment: I need to link the image to the root path. my code link whole row to the root path

Answer (score 1):

Your `<h1>` element will be 100% so that's why the whole row is a link. If you place the link outside the `<h1>` then only the image will be a link.